# Substring datafame string column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substring

I have a dataframe with one column:

```
x = data.frame(col = c('PS-01','PS-02','PS-03','PS-04','PS-05','PS-06')

  )
```

I want to substring it with stringr and get new dataframe with int after PS- which lookslike this:

```
x_new = data.frame(col = c(01,02,03,04,05,06)
```

How could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
gsub("PS-", "", x)
```

`gsub()` searches in `x` for the first argument(`"PS-"`) and replaces it with the second argument (`""`).

And here the `stringr` version:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(x, "PS-", "")
```

Comment: i need with package stringr or stringi

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringr`'s `str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(x$col, "(?<=PS-)\\d+")
#[1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06"
```

Or using the same pattern in base R :

```
unlist(regmatches(x$col, gregexpr("(?<=PS-)\\d+", x$col, perl = TRUE)))
```